# Building a text based game in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and am doing a small text based game in python. The objective is to be able to move room to room. I keep receiving a key error as python isn't recognizing one of the rooms. After I reach the living room I am then given a key error that says this:

```
if command in rooms[current_room].keys():
KeyError: 'Living room'
```

```
rooms = {
        'Entrance room': {'East': 'Master Bedroom'},
        'Master Bedroom': {'North': 'Family room'},
        'Family room': {'East': 'Dining Room', 'South': 'Master Bedroom'},
        'Dining Room': {'South': 'Living room', 'West': 'Family room'},
        'Living Room': {'South': 'Kitchen'},
        'Kitchen': {'South': 'Secret room', 'West': 'Master bedroom'},
        'Secret Room': {'West': 'Dungeon', 'North': 'Kitchen'},
        'Dungeon': {'East': 'Secret room'}
}
instructions = 'Welcome to the dragon slayer game, reach the dungeon to win. To move type: go North, go East, go West, go South'
directions = ['go North', 'go South', 'go East', 'go West']

print(instructions)
current_room = 'Entrance room'

while True:
    if current_room == 'Dungeon':
        print('Congratulations! You have reached the Dungeon and defeated the Dragon!')
        break
    
    print('You are in the {}.'.format(current_room))

    
    command = input('\nWhat do you want to do? ')  
    if command in directions:
        command = command.split()[1]
        if command in rooms[current_room].keys():
            current_room = rooms[current_room][command]
            print(current_room)
        else:
            
            print('You cant go that way!')
    
    elif command == 'exit':
        print('Thanks for playing!')
        break
    
    else:
        print('Invalid input')
```

Comment: "Living room" is not equal to "Living Room" - check your capitalisation.

Comment: Even more troublesome is that you're constructing an iterable from the keys of your dict, then checking  that iterable for membership.  That entirely defeats the purpose of using a dict.  Bad, bad code.  Just change it to `if command in rooms[current_room]:`  That will run in constant rather than linear time.

Comment: I changed that as well. Thank you. Looks like I don't understand that .keys method as much as I thought I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python dictionary keys are case-sensitive. You are checking for 'Living room' instead of 'Living Room' which is present in the dictionary. Note that the letter 'r' should be a capital.